# How to link/load .rodata section when loading BPF program with raw syscalls?

Tags: rust, ebpf, xdp-bpf

This question became longer than I expected. Since BPF is very new, it's possible there is no precise answer.

I am trying to load a "hello world" eBPF program onto the XDP attachment point. I want to do this using raw syscalls and *without* using `libbpf`, `bpftool`, `xdp-loader`, etc.

My kernel release is `6.5.0-9-generic`.

The BPF program is:

```c
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/version.h>

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    bpf_printk("In xdp_prog_simple\n");
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
__u32 _version SEC("version") = LINUX_VERSION_CODE;
```

And compiled with:

```bash
clang -O2 -g -Wall -target bpf -c bpf.c -o bpf.o
```

And the output of `llvm-objdump --no-show-raw-insn --dr bpf.o` is:

```
Disassembly of section xdp:

0000000000000000 <xdp_prog_simple>:
       0:   r1 = 0x0 ll
        0000000000000000:  R_BPF_64_64  .rodata
       2:   r2 = 0x14
       3:   call 0x6
       4:   r0 = 0x2
       5:   exit
```

I'm trying to load this `bpf.o` file using a Rust program. I extract the bytes from the `xdp` section and reference these in the attribute passed to the `BPF_PROG_LOAD` command of the `SYS_bpf` syscall:

(This code is **not** the problem. Including it for context, and because I haven't seen many Rust examples on the internet, so it could be helpful for future readers)

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;
use crate::ffi::bpf;
use crate::ffi::syscall::check_err;
use crate::Error;
use object::{Object, ObjectSection};

const LOG_BUF_SIZE: usize = 65536;
static mut BPF_LOG_BUF: [u8; LOG_BUF_SIZE] = [0; LOG_BUF_SIZE];

pub fn load_xdp_program(elf: &[u8], section: &str) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let obj = object::File::parse(elf).map_err(|err| Error::Boxed(Box::new(err)))?;

    // Extract bytes from the program section ("xdp" in this example)
    let text = obj
        .section_by_name(section)
        .ok_or_else(|| Error::NotFound("program section not found"))?
        .data()
        .map_err(|err| Error::Boxed(Box::new(err)))?;

    // Extract the license bytes
    let license = obj
        .section_by_name("license")
        .ok_or_else(|| Error::NotFound("section 'license' not found"))?
        .data()
        .map_err(|err| Error::Boxed(Box::new(err)))?;

    // Extract the kernel version bytes
    let version = {
        let data: [u8; 4] = obj
            .section_by_name("version")
            .ok_or_else(|| Error::NotFound("section 'version' not found"))?
            .data()
            .map_err(|err| Error::Boxed(Box::new(err)))?
            .try_into()
            .map_err(|err| Error::Boxed(Box::new(err)))?;
        u32::from_le_bytes(data)
    };

    let attr = &bpf::ProgramAttr {
        prog_type: XDP_PROG_TYPE,
        insn_cnt: (text.len() / size_of::<bpf::Insn>()) as u32,
        insns: ptr_to_u64(text),
        license: ptr_to_u64(license),
        log_level: 1,
        log_size: LOG_BUF_SIZE as u32,
        log_buf: ptr_to_u64(unsafe { &BPF_LOG_BUF }),
        kern_version: version,
        prog_flags: 0,
        prog_name: *b"xdp_prog_simple\0",
        prog_ifindex: 0,
        expected_attach_type: 37, // BPF_XDP
        prog_btf_fd: 0,
        func_info_rec_size: 0,
        func_info: 0,
        func_info_cnt: 0,
        line_info_rec_size: 0,
        line_info: 0,
        line_info_cnt: 0,
        attach_btf_id: 0,
        attach: bpf::AttachFd { object_fd: 0 },
        core_relo_cnt: 0,
        fd_array: 0,
        core_relos: 0,
        core_relo_rec_size: 0,
    };

    let prog_fd = check_err(unsafe {
        libc::syscall(
            libc::SYS_bpf,
            bpf::cmd::PROG_LOAD,
            attr as *const _ as *const libc::c_void,
            size_of::<bpf::BpfAttr>(),
        ) as i32
    });

    match prog_fd {
        Ok(fd) => Ok(fd),
        Err(err) => {
            let msg = String::from_utf8_lossy(unsafe { &BPF_LOG_BUF });
            eprintln!("Failed to load BPF program. Log buffer:\n\n{msg}");
            Err(err)
        }
    }
}
```

I build and call this as `sudo` to make sure it has root permissions:

```
cargo build --release --bin xdp-loader
sudo ./target/release/xdp-loader bpf.o
```

Which returns an error from the log buffer:

```
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
0: (18) r1 = 0x0                      ; R1_w=0
2: (b7) r2 = 20                       ; R2_w=20
3: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6
R1 type=scalar expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value, mem, ringbuf_mem, buf, trusted_ptr_
processed 3 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

And the BPF syscall return with error code 13: permission denied.

This seems to be implying that the register `r1` is a type `scalar` when it should be type `fp`. This is confusing to me. As far as I understand, `r1` should be carrying the address to context structure `struct xdp_md *ctx`, according [to these docs.](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/bpf/architecture/) I am not performing any pointer arithmetic, so it should not be converted to a scalar.

I think this is because `struct xdp_md *ctx` is not used, so it is compiled out. It is instead used for BPF calling convention to invoke the `bpf_printk` helper, which is actually a macro that is replaced by `bpf_trace_printk`.

When invoked, register `r1` is used to point at the `"In xdp_prog_simple\n"` string. It loaded an immediate 64-bit `0x0` address which is a zero-offset address into the `.rodata` section, which contains that string. This is the first argument to `bpf_printk`. Register `r2` is also loaded the immediate value `20` because that is the length of the `"In xdp_prog_simple\n"` string – it's the second argument to `bpf_trace_printk`.

But this doesn't explain the error:

```
R1 type=scalar expected=fp, pkt, pkt_meta, map_key, map_value, mem, ringbuf_mem, buf, trusted_ptr_
```

It expect `r1` to be a frame pointer, but it's a scalar.

I *think* this is because while I'm loading the `xdp` section containing the program byte code, I'm not loading the `.rodata` section, so this doesn't point anywhere, and the verifier interprets the `0x0` address as a scalar.

It seems like there needs to be an intermediate linking/loading step in order to make `.rodata` accessible by the BPF JIT. This is [corroborated by this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73479640/3668541), which implies that `libbpf` does it automatically. If I rewrite my code:

```
SEC("xdp")
int xdp_prog_simple(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    char msg[] = "In xdp_prog_simple\n";
    bpf_trace_printk(msg, sizeof(msg));
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

The string is stored inline, and not in a different section:

```
Disassembly of section xdp:

0000000000000000 <xdp_prog_simple>:
       0:   r1 = 0xa656c
       1:   *(u32 *)(r10 - 0x8) = r1
       2:   r1 = 0x706d69735f676f72 ll
       4:   *(u64 *)(r10 - 0x10) = r1
       5:   r1 = 0x705f706478206e49 ll
       7:   *(u64 *)(r10 - 0x18) = r1
       8:   r1 = r10
       9:   r1 += -0x18
      10:   r2 = 0x14
      11:   call 0x6
      12:   r0 = 0x2
      13:   exit
```

And the program loads successfully!

On my kernel version, `bpf_printk` [doesn't seem to do this restructure automatically:](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5/source/tools/lib/bpf/bpf_helpers.h#L297)

```c
/* Helper macro to print out debug messages */
#define bpf_printk(fmt, args...) ___bpf_pick_printk(args)(fmt, ##args)
```

My question: how can I do this automatically without need to split the declaration of the string and invocation of `bpf_trace_printk`? I believe I need to somehow link/load the string in the `.rodata` section as identified by the `R_BPF_64_64` relocation entry in the disassembly:

(Snippet from earlier)

```
0000000000000000 <xdp_prog_simple>:
       0:   r1 = 0x0 ll
        0000000000000000:  R_BPF_64_64  .rodata
```

So that it's stored inline with the bytecode. Is that correct? If so, how do I do this?

(My thinking is that I'll need scan the ELF file for relocation entries and use these to locate items in the .rodata section somehow, and then insert them into the bytecode directly)

I understand BPF is rather new and has sharp edges. Happy with any answer that points me in the right direction.